# Comparator for matching point in a range

Tags: c++, c++14

I need to create a `std::set` of ranges for finding matching points in these ranges. Each range is defined as follows:

```
struct Range {
    uint32_t start;
    uint32_t end;
    uint32_t pr;
};
```

In this structure `start`/`end` pair identify each range. `pr` identifies the priority of that range. It means if a single point falls into 2 different ranges, I like to return range with smaller `pr`. I like to create a `std::set` with a transparent comparator to match points like this:

```
struct RangeComparator {
    bool operator()(const Range& l, const Range& r) const {
        if (l.end < r.start)
            return true;
        if (l.end < r.end && l.pr >= r.pr)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    bool operator()(const Range& l, uint32_t p) const {
        if (p < l.start)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    bool operator()(uint32_t p, const Range& r) const {
        if (p < r.start)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    using is_transparent = int;
};

std::set<Range, RangeComparator> ranges;
ranges.emplace(100,250,1);
ranges.emplace(200,350,2);
auto v1 = ranges.find(110);  // <-- return range 1
auto v2 = ranges.find(210);  // <-- return range 1 because pr range 1 is less
auto v3 = ranges.find(260);  // <-- return range 2
```

**I know my comparators are wrong**. I wonder how I can write these 3 comparators to answer these queries correctly? Is it possible at all?

Comment: What is the *strict* ordering of those ranges? If one is entirely before the second, the first is a lesser one? If they overlap, the lesser one is the one that starts earlier? If they start the same, the lesser one is the one that terminates earlier? If yes, then I'm afraid it can't be done like this. You *need* to differentiate between ranges that *just* overlap. `pr` would be taken into account only if `start` and `end` were to be equal. It appears to me that `std::set`s requirements for its comparator make it impossible to do what you want *using the tools you want* but possible using other

Comment: As described, neither `std::set`, nor any other container in the C++ library can be used to implement a container of these classes, because there is no strict weak ordering, which is a requirement for ordered containers, and there is no viable hashing mechanism that can be used with unordered containers. A custom container needs to be coded that handles the described semantics of this class.

Comment: @Fureeish One issue is that I cannot visualize the ordering correctly, that's why I'm not sure if it is possible to write any comparator for this at all or not. I need to select comparator in a way to compare both points and ranges. I think strict ordering should be like this: if these ranges are disjoint, the ones comes first is less than other. if they are not, the one with less `pr` is less than other one. But I'm not sure 2nd part is correct.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for info. I thought that may be the case, but I needed to be sure before writing a container for it...

Comment: @Afshin I'm not sure it's a good idea because it searches through _all_ elements but perhaps you can get something out of [this](https://godbolt.org/z/oK9WYdn98)

Comment: *But I'm not sure 2nd part is correct.* This simple scheme is not strict. Consider A={1,3,2}, B={2,4,1}, C={3,5,0}, i.e. A and C do not overlap and B overlaps with A and C, priority ordering is C,B,A. Then B < A and C < B, but also A < C, which makes the relation intransitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` returns an element that compares *equivalent* to the argument. *Equivalent* means that it compares neither larger nor smaller in the strict weak ordering provided to the `std::set`.

Therefore, to make your use case work, you want all points in a range to compare equivalent to the range.

If two ranges overlap, then the points shared by the two ranges need to compare *equivalent* to both ranges. The priority doesn't matter for this, since the equivalence should presumably hold if only one of the ranges is present.

However, one of the defining properties of a strict weak ordering is that the property of comparing equivalent is transitive. Therefore in this ordering the two ranges must then also compare equal in order to satisfy the requirements of `std::set`.

Therefore, as long as the possible ranges are not completely separated, the only valid strict weak ordering is the one that compares all ranges and points equivalent.

This is however not an order that would give you what you want.

This analysis holds for all standard library associative containers, since they have the same requirements on the ordering.